# Export database by a certain parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

There is a database with a lot of tables.
I need to export a certain user with all his information from the database.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
Select * from * where user_id='123';
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? You have tagged both in your question. The best answer depends on which brand of RDBMS you are using, so be specific.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. I'm using oracle and SQLDeveloper as DBMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that isn't valid SQL syntax. The table name has to be explicit in the query.

We could run a separate query for each table that includes a column named `user_id`...

```
SELECT * FROM mytable        WHERE user_id = '123';
SELECT * FROM othertable     WHERE user_id = '123';
SELECT * FROM anothertable   WHERE user_id = '123';
SELECT * FROM anotherone     WHERE user_id = '123';
```

to help us generate the statements, we can get a list of tables in the current database that contain a column named `user_id` ...

```
SELECT CONCAT('`',c.table_schema,'`.`',c.table_name,'`') AS `-- table`  
  FROM information_schema.columns c
 WHERE c.table_schema = DATABASE()
   AND c.column_name = 'user_id'
 ORDER BY c.table_name
```

We could also extend the expression in the SELECT list to generate the complete SELECT statement.

Comment: that didn't work 100%, but thanks for sending me in the right direction :)

Comment: The syntax in this answer is for MySQL not Oracle. (At the time this answer was posted, the question was tagged as `mysql`.)